# MySQL一括置換

Tags: mysql, sql

http://www.shinbo.org/archives/2836

```
UPDATE ITEMS SET MOVIE=REPLACE(MOVIE,”.flv”,”.mp4″);
```

こちらをもとにWordPressのカスタムフィールドの文字を全て一括置換すると、なぜかカスタムフィールドが全滅してしまいました。Select文で調べると、値と名前が同じになってしまっていました。

というのが先月にあり、バックアップも取っていなかったため全て手作業で治す羽目になって以来、トラウマであまりSQL文を使いたくないんですが今回また置換したいことがありまして、一度テスト仮実行したいのですがどうすればできますか？

今回実行したいのはWordpress wp_posts post_contentのリンクタグです。

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content= REPLACE(
    post_content,
    '<a href="http://',
    '<a href="https://"')
WHERE post_content like '%<a href="https://"%';
```

・PHPMyAdminはセキュリティ上インストールしません。
・バックアップは成功したときの削除方法や、失敗して復元した際、厳密に復元されるかどうかわからないので取りません。
・他にも複雑な文字列を置換したいので成功した暁にまた実行したいです、なのでWordPressの置換プラグインは使いません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

失敗したくなければBEGINを使ってトランザクションに含めればいいです。うまくUPDATEできていればCOMMIT,思った通りにならなければROLLBACKすれば元に戻ります。

**UPDATEをしくじったら元に戻す例**

```
BEGIN;
    UPDATE ITEMS SET MOVIE=REPLACE(MOVIE,”.flv”,”.mp4″);
    SELECT * FROM ITEMS; -- 確認用
ROLLBACK; -- 失敗していたら元に戻す
```

**UPDATEがうまく行ったら確定する例**

```
BEGIN;
    UPDATE ITEMS SET MOVIE=REPLACE(MOVIE,”.flv”,”.mp4″);
    SELECT * FROM ITEMS; -- 確認用
COMMIT; -- 確定操作
```

mysqlのコマンドラインツールはデフォルトではオートコミットになっています。つまりUPDATE文を実行したらいきなり確定になります。これを手動コミットにするには

```
SET autocommit = 0;
```

とします。するとCOMMITかROLLBACKが常に必要になります。

バックアップは厳密に復元されるようにできています。テストDBを作って練習することをお勧めします。バックアップの無いデータは元から存在しないと思え、と私は習いました。

Comment: 助かりました、Google検索しても見つからなかったため、こういうのを探していました。

Comment: 予定通り一度実行すると、構文を間違えていて失敗しました。
rollbackで戻して再び確認して再度実行するとうまくいってcommitして成功しました。
ありがとうございます。
バックアップとアウトコミット設定も感謝です。

Comment: `set autocommit=0;` にすると`begin;`を省略しても良いということでしょうか？
その状態でupdate文を実行して`rollback;`も`commit;`も忘れていた場合、自動でrollbackされますか？

Comment: そういうことになります！どちらも忘れていた場合、コマンドラインのツールを終了した時点でセッションが切れます。切れた時にロールバックされます。

Comment: わかりました、この度は本当にありがとうございました